# If NaOH is a Brönsted-Lowry base then, what is its conjugate acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Brönsted-Lowry theory doesn't go against but adds to the Arrhenius theory on bases and acids.
$\ce{NaOH}$ is an Arrhenius base because it releases hydroxide ions in water solution.
NaOH is also a Brönsted-Lowry base because it dissociates in water and its hydroxide ion reacts with water(which acts as an acid).

$\ce{NaOH = Na+ + OH-}$

So if the "actual" Brönsted-Lowry base in NaOH is the hydroxide ion then is the conjugate acid here water? Is the conjugate acid of NaOH, water?

My book on the other hand, says that "$\ce{Na+}$ is the conjugate weak acid to NaOH which is a strong base. So when NaCl is dissolved in water, $\ce{Na+}$ will not react with water at all" .  But how can $\ce{Na+}$ be an acid when it doesn't have any hydrogen to give?

So which one is the conjugate acid, $\ce{H2O}$ or $\ce{Na+}$ and how can $\ce{Na+}$ be an acid at all?

Can $\ce{Na+}$ be a conjugate lewis acid but not be a conjugate Brönsted-Lowry acid?

Comment: Duplicates https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35673/what-is-the-conjugate-acid-of-naoh-using-the-br%c3%b8nsted-lowry-definition-of-acids https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/97341/is-sodium-hydroxide-a-bronsted-lowry-base https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/98084/how-can-arrhenius-bases-also-be-br%c3%b8nsted-lowry-bases and low hanging ones at that.

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate acid to the [Brønsted-Lowry base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%B8nsted%E2%80%93Lowry_acid%E2%80%93base_theory) $\ce{OH−}$
is $\ce{H2O}$, just added a proton to $\ce{OH−}$.

$$\ce{B(aq) + H+(aq) <=> BH+(aq)}$$

$$\ce{OH-(aq) + H+(aq) <=> H2O(l)}$$

where $\ce{B} = \ce{OH-}$

OTOH, $\ce{H2O}$ is also the conjugate base to $\ce{H3O+}$.

$\ce{Na+(aq)}$ is an extremely weak [Lewis acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_acids_and_bases). But in a gaseous phase, as a naked ion, it reacts with Lewis base $\ce{Cl-}$, forming an ionic pair $\ce{Na+Cl-}$.

$\ce{Na+}$ could be formally considered as a conjugate Arrhenius acid to $\ce{NaOH}$, but I am not sure if the concept of conjugate pairs is ever used in the Arrhenius theory.

Comment: In Arrhenius there's no conjugate acid, but $\ce{Na(H2O)+}$ complex can be considered one in B-L.